React Swiper Navigation not working properly with breakpoints
I'm having a problem with Swiper React (v. 11.1.9), I need the navigation arrows to appear on only some devices. I set up the component using the breakpoints object to conditionally display the navigation.
When I change the screen size manually through the browser with the application running it works correctly, but if I load the screen directly in the resolution (width 450 for example) it displays the arrows and they don't work.
Any thoughts?.
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { forwardRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import 'swiper/css/bundle';
import { EffectCoverflow, Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import styles from './Slider.module.css';

const Slider = forwardRef(({ children }, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  return (
    <Swiper
      style={{
        '--swiper-pagination-color': '#FFF',
        '--swiper-theme-color': '#FFF'
      }}
      ref={ref}
      className={styles.swiper}
      modules={[Navigation, Pagination, EffectCoverflow]}
      spaceBetween={50}
      slidesPerView={5}
      navigation={{ enabled: false }}
      centeredSlides
      slideToClickedSlide
      pagination={{
        clickable: true
      }}
      coverflowEffect={{ slideShadows: false, rotate: 0 }}
      effect="coverflow"
      speed={800}
      breakpoints={{
        0: {
          navigation: {
            enabled: true
          },
          slidesPerView: 1.1
        },
        400: {
          navigation: {
            enabled: false
          },
          slidesPerView: 1.5,
          spaceBetween: 1
        },
        450: {
          navigation: {
            enabled: false
          },
          slidesPerView: 1.9,
          spaceBetween: 1
        },
        600: {
          navigation: {
            enabled: false
          },
          slidesPerView: 2
        },
        800: {
          navigation: {
            enabled: false
          },
          slidesPerView: 2.3
        },
        960: {
          navigation: {
            enabled: true
          },
          slidesPerView: 3.3,
          spaceBetween: 16
        }
      }}
    >
      {children?.map((child) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={child.key}>{child}</SwiperSlide>
      ))}
    </Swiper>
  );
});

Slider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export default Slider;


I already tried to use the onBreakpoint hook of the swiper itself to see if the component was being referenced correctly and it displayed the object correctly, that is, it knows that it is supposed to be false.
onBreakpoint={(swiper, breakpoint) => {
  console.log(`Breakpoint atingido: ${breakpoint}`);
  swiper.update();
}}

